# Import Database in DBProject using CommandLine or api

Tags: sql-server

It is possible to import a database in dbproject using SSDT. but is there any api or commands available to do the same thing automatically like silent installer.

i have a datawarehouse which depends on OLTP but the OLTP is maintained by other team. i want to create a dbproject for OLTP but the problem is to keep it updated whenever the OLTP changed by other team who are not using this DBProject. is there any way using commandline or any api that the OLTP could be imported to dbproject automatically without SSDT UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i searched a lot to do this. and finally came to know that microsoft didnt provide command line to update dbproject from database.  vice versa is possible using command line. 
i got below text on MSDN

> You cannot use VSDBCMD to import objects and settings into a data-tier
>   application component (DAC) project. You must use the Import DAC or
>   Import Script commands from within Visual Studio. For more
>   information, see How to: Import Database Objects from a Script, and
>   the following pages on the Microsoft Web site.

[The Site where i get to know you can not import dbproject from database using commandline/VSDBCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172135(v=vs.100).aspx)

finally i did it using codedUI to automate updating of DBProject from Database.