# Import or update an SSDT database project programatically

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-migration, sql-server-data-tools

I'm hoping to use an SSDT database project alongside a migration-based database development tool like [grate](https://erikbra.github.io/grate/). The idea here would be to use migration scripts as the source of truth for the database schema, but to import into the database project to generate the more complex change scripts (for which project compilation would provide extra confidence). I'm hoping that I could script a process that runs migration scripts, then recreates/updates the database project, so that it's automatically kept in sync.

Is it possible to programmatically import from a database into a new (or existing) SSDT database project? I'm looking to do something equivalent to [importing into a Database Project using SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/import-into-a-database-project?view=sql-server-ver16#bkmk_import_source_db), but programmatically.

I don't think that it is:

- I can't find any documentation to suggest that it is
- I've found a few SO answers stating that it's not:

  - [Import Database in DBProject using CommandLine or api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669828/import-database-in-dbproject-using-commandline-or-api)
  - [How to update an SSDT project from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948453/how-to-update-an-ssdt-project-from-the-command-line)
  - [Updating a Visual Studio SQL Server Database project from a database using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961361/updating-a-visual-studio-sql-server-database-project-from-a-database-using-comma)

The most recent answer is nearly 6 years old, and I'm not certain that the situation hasn't changed since then. It would be nice to have a definitive answer either way.

Comment: You can extract dacpac automatically, but I'm pretty sure that importing that into the project in automated way is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for commenting  Yes, I suspect that's true. My assumption is that it's not possible, but I'd like to be certain.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev I think maybe I misinterpreted your comment as having less confidence than you meant to imply. Having re-read your comment, I think that when you say "you're pretty sure" you mean you're almost certain. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I haven't followed news this year, but there was no such solution at the end of 2021